# A/B multivariate platform that works with subdomains

Tags: google-website-optimizer, multivariate-testing, usability-testing

I am about to run some a/b and multivariate tests for some landing pages.

In the past I used google website optimizer, but I always had problems when dealing with subdomains.

The documentation for gwo is poor and the various approaches I tried, made me loose lots of time..

I am considering to use a commercial / alternative platform and I would like to know your opinions.

My tipical scenario is to present a landing page and a conversion page located on a subdomain.

Comment: GWO actually has [pretty good documentation](http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117912) for subdomains, and is, in my opinion, your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website has a list of tools: http://www.wingify.com/conversion-blog/15-free-ab-split-testing-resources/

Some are free.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/) is the best A/B testing tool that I know. It's a little pricey, but worth the price IMO. They support [cross-domain testing](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/easiest-way-to-track-conversions-across-multiple-domains-using-third-party-cookies/) which should cover what you need.